# C# Get all names from SQL and return as a list

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to get more familiar with SQL and C# so I'm working on a simple app, right now I have a populated SQL database, but I would like to get all my names from my Persons Table and put them in a combo box, but when I try to get all the names I can only get the first name in the Table.
This is how I am trying to do it.

```
using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Name] FROM [Persons].[dbo].[Test]", sqlConnection))
{
    var names = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Comment: `ExecuteScalar` is for when your query only returns one row.  It looks like you actually want to use `ExecuteReader`.  Check out it's [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx) which has an example of how to use it.

Comment: I would suggest stop playing with SQLConenctions, commands, readers, ect.. and just use EntityFramework.. Point it to the existing database and most of the code will be just generated for you :)

Comment: @Marty should it not be good to understand how SQL works though?

Comment: Disagree with @Marty, EF is fine, but it is not the only good way.

Comment: @JoakimCarlsson - well isn't that the point of OOP ? to abstract stuff away ?

Comment: anyone suggesting you not learn how to properly code in ADO.NET framework ignore them with extreme prejudice.

Comment: A compromise between EF and ADO.Net is Dapper.  It handles a lot of the boiler plate code that you write for ADO.Net without all the overhead and potential performance issues of EF.  But you'd definitely want to learn ADO.Net first.

Comment: Yes of course.. every programmer should learn all the low level stuff.. and get back to programming assembler :)

Comment: ADO.NET is core .NET simple as that, EF and many other bloated frameworks are gumming up simple apps.

Comment: @Marty I do think every programmer should learn assembler to get an understanding of what is going on when they make a computer program. They may not need to keep or maintain their assembler skills, but it doesn't hurt to have some exposure to it to have a basic concrete understanding of how programming actually works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually want to use a [`SqlDataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
var names = new List<string>();
using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Name] FROM [Persons].[dbo].[Test]", sqlConnection))
{
    using(var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
       while(reader.Read())
       {
          names.Add(reader["Name"].ToString());
       }
    }
}
```

Note that [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) only gets the first column of the first returning row.

Answer (score 0):

instead of ExecuteScalar do this:

```
using( var rdr = command.ExecuteReader() )
{
    while( rdr.Read() )
    {
          var name = rdr.GetString(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend not using `GetString(0)` what if the schema of the datbase changed and their is a column inserted before the Name column also what if the `Column["Name"]` is not in the `ordinal position of `0` in the database.. it's always better in my opinion to qualify the column name by string value not index value.. also your code does not show where to add the reader results to List<T> partial answer at best..!

Comment: it was just an example... the OP question centered around getting a list.

Comment: where in your code are you populating a list..? anyway this is not really a good answer in my opinion..!

Comment: I'm wounded to hear this.

Answer (score 0):

Use ExecuteReader instead; make sure you declare the List outside of the loop or it will be out of scope when you need it.

```
var names = new List<string>();
using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Name] FROM [Persons].[dbo].[Test]", sqlConnection))
{
    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        names.Add(reader[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()` returns a single value, which is what the word **scalar** means. You need to declare a `SqlDataReader rdr;` and initialize it via `rdr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()`. Then you need to loop through the rows with a while loop that checks if the reader has more rows to read via `while(rdr.Read())`. This will both a) tell you if there are any remaining unread rows via the return value (hence it being your while condition) and b) advance the reader to the first unread row.

I strongly recommend the following article to get you up to speed on using SqlCommand in C#:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlcommand